# Azure PostgreSQL pg_dump impact on backup "chain"

Tags: postgresql, backup, azure

I'm a SQL Serve DBA new to PostgreSQL.  Does pg_dump have an impact on the backup chain, i.e., in SQL Server if I needed a copy of a database I would peform a COPYONLY backup so as not to break the lsn sequence.  Does pg_dump impact the native Azure backups being performed in the background?

Answer (score 0):

If Azure is anything like PostgreSQL, an online physical backup won't interfere with `pg_dump` and vice versa (except that both will generate I/O load).

`pg_dump` uses a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction which guarantees a consistent backup.